# Internet routing table breaks 512,000 routes

Tags: networking, routing, router

Looks like with all the mass IP grabs as well as subletting of space, things have finally hit the 512K mark.

Anyone on the raw end of an upstream router that ran out of route space?

How do most routers handle route exhaustion? Does it still operate, just with a < full table? Or does it break? Or does it end up doing a lot of the routing in software?

Comment: If you want to _talk_ about it, come and visit us in chat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple fix for this, at least when it comes to the most popular Cisco routers:

```
mls cef maximum-routes ip 768
```

This requires a reboot.

Also see Cisco's documentation about adjusting the TCAM to allocate more IPv4 space (and less IPv6): http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/117712-problemsolution-cat6500-00.html

Source: http://packetlife.net/blog/2014/may/6/global-ipv4-routing-table-hits-500k-routes/